# (Bootstrap) My background gets cut off near the bottom

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a website for a school project using Bootstrap, and in my website the background gets cut off toward the bottom of my content. It should continue to the bottom of the content. I can't figure out why, can anyone help me?
Here's a Dropbox download link for the website. Sorry it's not in a JSFiddle.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yndtqv5em7m8fdd/test.zip?dl=0

Comment: dropbox link doesn't work with a zip file

Comment: @Gerard Yeah, sorry. I guess you have to download it. It's only 280 kB, I hope that's ok.

Comment: @JeremiS you need a clearfix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Jeremy's Website</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" role="main">
            <div class="body">
                <section class="contentpage" id="page1">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <header>
                            <h1>Summary</h1>
                            <h2>Subheading placeholder</h2>
                        </header>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bodypg">Quorum eiusmod adipisicing. Arbitror enim iudicem in sed cillum dolor malis 
                        vidisse, velit consequat non firmissimum, occaecat se eiusmod, expetendis iis 
                        fore cernantur, labore praesentibus quibusdam minim mentitum, mandaremus veniam 
                        id consequat efflorescere, commodo tamen dolore incurreret labore. Quorum 
                        efflorescere appellat velit quibusdam, et incididunt philosophari, occaecat an 
                        summis mentitum, offendit illum quamquam ullamco sed ullamco praesentibus non 
                        incurreret quo do legam aliquip, possumus quid ad admodum eruditionem et fugiat 
                        de quamquam do cillum. Offendit ut ingeniis. Aliqua philosophari probant illum 
                        senserit, ad nescius coniunctione, admodum eu eram ne mentitum voluptatibus do 
                        incurreret. A quid despicationes. Aute firmissimum mandaremus quis occaecat, 
                        anim e incurreret sed duis an enim instituendarum aliquip cillum quibusdam, do 
                        fugiat excepteur iudicem, malis incididunt nam dolor multos, senserit sint 
                        ullamco aliquip si pariatur est laboris e mandaremus enim ab singulis 
                        fidelissimae. Offendit dolore offendit ad de legam illum legam cupidatat, se o 
                        eram veniam velit hic magna offendit comprehenderit hic id illum possumus 
                        distinguantur, ex summis probant incididunt a eu aliquip an eiusmod, cupidatat 
                        voluptatibus aut doctrina.<br><br>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="contentpage" id="page2">
                    <div class="col-md-12" >
                        <header>
                            <h1>Page 2</h1>
                            <h2>this is placeholder text</h2>
                        </header>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bodypg">Velit familiaritatem incididunt dolor mandaremus. Aut consequat te occaecat ea 
                        commodo philosophari qui excepteur, do ab illustriora iis qui ex ipsum amet 
                        eram, mandaremus ut cernantur ad malis expetendis a aliquip, mandaremus non elit 
                        ingeniis non a culpa senserit firmissimum. Deserunt relinqueret ita appellat, 
                        ullamco sunt e vidisse praetermissum an velit probant e labore labore, iis 
                        quorum tempor voluptate. Ullamco exquisitaque ut cernantur. Cupidatat est quid 
                        ullamco. Minim ex proident ubi qui esse quis nam incididunt, mentitum velit 
                        consequat expetendis o iis aliquip firmissimum. Esse admodum despicationes, 
                        varias cupidatat te praesentibus si senserit varias id officia imitarentur, 
                        senserit sunt veniam excepteur irure. 
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="contentpage" id="page3">
                    <div class="col-md-12" >
                        <header>
                            <h1>Page 3</h1>
                            <h2>this is placeholder text</h2>
                        </header>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bodypg">An id exquisitaque, sed irure quis amet ingeniis, ullamco multos vidisse tempor 
                        ea ut magna litteris domesticarum. Incurreret quorum do pariatur concursionibus 
                        qui eiusmod legam o commodo coniunctione non eram excepteur o eruditionem a 
                        noster probant transferrem. Ab iis voluptatibus et dolore graviterque incididunt 
                        sint quibusdam ab ex sunt litteris nostrud est mandaremus ex culpa singulis, 
                        appellat quem incurreret laborum, senserit qui nisi a ne o familiaritatem te 
                        senserit et ingeniis. Tamen ita ad fugiat pariatur o mandaremus noster eram te 
                        minim, quis incididunt iis fugiat quae de o esse se cillum, dolor officia est 
                        exercitation, si proident est iudicem, ad te malis dolore illum hic senserit in 
                        deserunt. Doctrina sint nisi ad dolor, ad est fidelissimae, quid non iudicem, ab 
                        culpa praesentibus, dolor doctrina sed nescius, veniam mandaremus ingeniis, 
                        nostrud culpa deserunt nostrud, ne ita quid nescius. Commodo sunt veniam nam 
                        legam. In sunt de nulla, est excepteur eruditionem, ex esse vidisse consectetur, 
                        non ut minim veniam esse ex admodum quorum eram an tamen, eu ipsum fugiat ut 
                        mandaremus, in cillum singulis offendit, veniam possumus iis vidisse.
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="contentpage" id="page4">
                    <div class="col-md-12" >
                        <header>
                            <h1>Page 4</h1>
                            <h2>this is placeholder text</h2>
                        </header>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bodypg">Nulla voluptate do voluptate de sint pariatur si firmissimum, occaecat sed 
                        cupidatat ab do laboris exquisitaque, ubi quorum senserit o mentitum 
                        distinguantur iis laborum, id ubi culpa fugiat cillum ut senserit quis non 
                        deserunt reprehenderit. Iudicem exquisitaque non admodum. Ita magna ex multos. 
                        Non hic velit expetendis ut fabulas id aliquip, tempor fore senserit et tempor 
                        culpa irure a amet. Mentitum qui duis tempor an a nisi ullamco proident. Irure 
                        ex doctrina iis officia ne legam, sunt litteris instituendarum, quid aut 
                        laboris, velit arbitrantur excepteur quae ullamco ut eu dolore veniam duis 
                        quibusdam, a cillum eram quorum singulis iis quem o nescius iis ipsum. Consequat 
                        de nisi.
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="contentpage" id="page5">
                    <div class="col-md-12" >
                        <header>
                            <h1>Page 5</h1>
                            <h2>this is placeholder text</h2>
                        </header>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bodypg">Nulla senserit ab ipsum illum ut voluptate noster tamen in esse. Cillum pariatur 
                        litteris. Nam magna officia. Velit an excepteur ea magna. Ingeniis anim o 
                        quibusdam consectetur. Eu quorum deserunt. Velit expetendis hic commodo, 
                        singulis distinguantur ita tempor, e ne enim velit ipsum de o legam singulis 
                        graviterque, e quis aute malis admodum a quid mentitum efflorescere, commodo 
                        familiaritatem se litteris sed eu quem aliqua se deserunt. Arbitror aute 
                        appellat aut nam nam veniam fugiat esse in tempor fugiat iis nostrud 
                        sempiternum, labore o proident in quem hic se multos iudicem praetermissum qui 
                        tamen concursionibus aliquip labore quibusdam a noster imitarentur senserit 
                        fugiat excepteur ita qui summis nescius appellat.<br><br>

                        <div class="text-justify fancy">
                            <div class="blockquote">In a series of experiments on small numbers of gamers (10 to 14 people in each study), the researchers reported that gamers with previous experience of playing such action video games were better at perceptual tasks such as pattern discrimination than gamers with less experience.<br>
                            In another experiment, they trained gamers that had little previous experience of playing action games, giving them 50 hours practice. It was showed that these gamers performed much better on perceptual tasks than they had prior to their training. </div>
                            <footer>~ Mark Griffiths, The Conversation <a href="http://theconversation.com/playing-video-games-is-good-for-your-brain-heres-how-34034">(source)</a></footer>
                        </div><br>

                        <strong>Survey results:</strong><br>
                        Excepteur et aliqua quibusdam ne qui legam doctrina transferrem. Enim pariatur 
                        ne labore quae ubi amet commodo singulis. Legam expetendis est multos quid, de 
                        duis arbitrantur de et ita legam quae sint, dolor singulis ubi proident. Si hic 
                        consectetur, laborum illum occaecat admodum. Enim cupidatat eruditionem sed 
                        ingeniis aliqua aliqua senserit duis id labore si litteris si duis tractavissent 
                        laborum amet nescius. Anim occaecat ex iudicem an si nulla tamen eu ullamco, 
                        enim singulis iis instituendarum, ut nostrud qui nescius, nostrud aliqua ea 
                        laboris graviterque, hic cillum voluptate laborum o ubi quid arbitror, ne quae 
                        quamquam. Do proident ne incurreret. Dolor domesticarum consequat enim quibusdam te culpa 
                        mandaremus litteris. Irure appellat aut incurreret, ubi admodum philosophari a 
                        tempor quo fore excepteur de varias cernantur imitarentur. Velit imitarentur 
                        mandaremus labore excepteur. Excepteur labore occaecat. Fore ea si tamen 
                        probant, eiusmod irure a mandaremus transferrem. Eram a mentitum et elit, in 
                        veniam ne multos.<br><br>

                        <strong>One short answer question in my survey was "Why do you think playing games makes your marks worse/better?"<br>Following are some student responses.</strong><br><br>

                        <img src="img/piemarks.png">
                        <div class="text-justify fancy"><div class="opinion">Opinion: Worsens</div>
                            <div class="blockquote">I don't necessarily think that my personal activities affect my schoolwork, but if you play too much, preventing completion of schoolwork and revision, and importantly omitting proper sleep if staying up late, it becomes a problem. So controlled playing hours must happen. </div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>


                        <div class="text-justify fancy"><div class="opinion">Opinion: Improves</div>
                            <div class="blockquote">Yes </div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>


                        <div class="text-justify fancy"><div class="opinion">Opinion: Worsens</div>
                            <div class="blockquote">In the right amount it's fine, even good. But playing a lot will distract from school work, which is something that definitely does improve your marks.</div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>


                        <div class="text-justify fancy"><div class="opinion">Opinion: Improves</div>
                            <div class="blockquote">It can depending what type of game you play. Usually puzzle games can improve them the most.</div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>


                        <div class="text-justify fancy"><div class="opinion">Opinion: Worsens</div>
                            <div class="blockquote">It is very addictive, and in my opinion, there is infinite amount of study that could be done, and playing is just completely wasting the limited amount of time I have. </div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>


                        <div class="text-justify fancy"><div class="opinion">Opinion: Improves</div>
                            <div class="blockquote">I believe the strategy involved when playing video games is a good way to train your brain to be able to make quick descions.</div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>


                        <div class="text-justify fancy"><div class="opinion">Opinion: Worsens</div>
                            <div class="blockquote">It distracts me from doing study/homework</div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>


                        <div class="text-justify fancy"><div class="opinion">Opinion: Improves</div>
                            <div class="blockquote">Relieving my stress and tension by having fun and playing games keeps worries off my mind and allows me to focus on school when i need to. As well as certain games improving cognitive functions.</div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>


                        <div class="text-justify fancy"><div class="opinion">Opinion: Worsens</div>
                            <div class="blockquote">Well my marks haven't exactly gotten better, have they?</div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>


                        <div class="text-justify fancy"><div class="opinion">Opinion: Worsens</div>
                            <div class="blockquote">Takes time out of my possible study time and serves more as a distraction above anything else.</div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </section>
                <section class="contentpage" id="page6">
                    <div class="col-md-12" >
                        <header>
                            <h1>Page 6</h1>
                            <h2>this is placeholder text</h2>
                        </header>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bodypg">De quo minim culpa enim id dolore familiaritatem mandaremus fore doctrina. Illum 
                        arbitrantur ingeniis malis ingeniis, mentitum aute ex singulis despicationes, 
                        aliquip sed irure ne nam incididunt ab iudicem, id cupidatat est incurreret qui 
                        laboris quorum in tempor exquisitaque, an duis pariatur arbitrantur sed non 
                        eiusmod nam pariatur. Ingeniis duis multos non quem, noster doctrina fabulas ita 
                        appellat varias quae cupidatat legam, e irure probant instituendarum si e 
                        quibusdam tractavissent in cillum cupidatat ne dolor quae et ita tamen varias 
                        qui singulis, offendit legam sint admodum multos. Velit ullamco de 
                        familiaritatem. Incurreret fore nostrud, est si exquisitaque si fugiat 
                        comprehenderit mentitum summis admodum, commodo sunt malis ita cillum, est irure 
                        cernantur illustriora, vidisse de amet quamquam ad quo iudicem sempiternum est 
                        duis deserunt eruditionem. Velit aliquip e consectetur ubi incurreret dolor 
                        dolore quamquam aliqua, cupidatat cohaerescant a ingeniis id consequat nisi 
                        minim non nulla. Arbitror iis occaecat ad anim consequat et incurreret ex iis 
                        cillum voluptatibus hic quem voluptate de minim culpa ut nulla an nescius aut 
                        nisi in consequat quid quem id nisi ea eu laboris de nostrud ad malis excepteur 
                        firmissimum. Incurreret nulla summis qui elit, se labore cupidatat non incididunt noster 
                        eiusmod arbitror ne litteris anim in cupidatat philosophari. Multos illustriora 
                        arbitror magna quamquam sed cernantur e minim. Sed minim velit aute fabulas, o 
                        sunt fore non iudicem ea ex veniam eiusmod admodum ea non qui voluptatibus. Fore 
                        quamquam comprehenderit. Doctrina et eiusmod. Ne anim et anim iis do eram 
                        ingeniis. Minim quamquam nostrud, excepteur nisi quem si labore.
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <div class="logo">
                <div class="tagline">
                    © 2017, Jeremy 
                </div><br>

                <p class="contact">
                    lorem ipsum
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your CSS , problem is `floats` inside `.contentpage` you need a clearfix.

If parent(contentpage) contains `float` elements inside it, automatically parents `height` gets collapsed, so you need a `clearfix` to retain the parents `height`.

CSS

```
.contentpage {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-left: 20px solid #FF4B3B;
    border-right: 20px solid #FF4B3B;
}
.contentpage::after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

First edit

## 1

`h1 {
/* let the bootstrap handle the size */
/*font-size: 3em;*/ 
}`

## 2

`img {
/*add this*/
    width: 100%;
}`

and there you are

Comment: @JeremiS the problem is so simple

Answer (score 0):

Just give `bootstrap` class `row` along with contentpage to 6th section i.e, section having `id="page6"`.

```
<section class="contentpage row" id="page6">
```